# Decrypt the Particular column in linq

Tags: linq, asp.net-mvc-4, encryption

Decrypt the Particular column(i.e.Email) of a list from a list using linq.

Here is the code:

```
 List<sp_Ticketlist_Result> _dbData;          
            _dbData = _repository.GetTicket(UserId).ToList();
```

In this _dbData a column name Email.This email is decrypted.

Here is the class to encypt the Email  (AESCryptography.AES256_Decrypt).
I am try this code :

```
_dbData = (decrypted.ToList().Select(u => AESCryptography.AES256_Decrypt(u.Email))).ToList();
```

but not working.

I want to Fetch the list with the email column decrypted value.

Comment: I think you will need to fetch the list first and then decrypt.

Comment: In _dbData  i am getting the list

Comment: How do i decrypt a particular column using linq??

Comment: how do i decrypted columns with Entity Framework??

Comment: You can then take _dbData and iterate through the list decrypting the encrypted field and create a new list